# Can we add a custom URL into the info.plist in real time through the app ?

Tags: ios, swift, info.plist

I want to access other apps through custom URLs. And for that I need to add the custom URLs to the info.plist in real time through my app. So how can I add the new URLs programatically ?
And are there any restrictions in terms of iOS versions supporting this updation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app's bundle is read-only when it's installed on a device.

You can copy the plist file to a writable area, like your document directory, and modify that but I don't know what good it would do you.

If you're trying to save these URLs for later use, `NSUserDefaults` is a better idea.

Comment: My requirement is : Can I add to the list of URLs in real time. As in If I want to add a new URL, I should be able to do that from within my app. Secondly can I write into the plist from within my app ?  And thirdly how would NSUserDefaults suffice the requirement.

Comment: The important piece that you're leaving out, in order to get some of those answers, is what the URLs are being used for.  (But the one thing for sure is that you can't write into a plist that's part of the app bundle on a device unless you copy it somewhere else.)

Comment: Hi Philip, I am trying to open another app in my app. But I am geting an error ":924072] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "MyCameraTestApp://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme MyCameraTestApp"
MyCameraTestApp being the 2nd app I am trying to access.
Am I missing any tricks up here ?

Comment: I haven't done this but I think you need to have the schemes listed at the time you build your app.  Like: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl/